# How to generate Zumo sid from website side

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

I have a web app and a mobile app that I would like to share the same authentication. When the user goes to .auth/login/aad (for example), I am able to get the aad claims directly. When the user uses zumo on a mobile app, I can use the ProviderCredentials to get the matching aad claims. Is there a "generateSid" function I can use to take the web app login aad claims and generate the zumo sid so that they match?

To get the user claims from the web app side, I use

```
    private Response FlowPrincipal(NancyContext context)
    {
        var env = Get<IDictionary<string, object>>(context.Items, NancyMiddleware.RequestEnvironmentKey);
        if (env != null)
        {
            var principal = Get<IPrincipal>(env, "server.User") as ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (principal != null)
            {
                context.CurrentUser = new ClaimsPrincipalUserIdentity(principal);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This gives me a user id directly from aad, but not from zumo (the "sid").

[image]

It takes a query to the server to go from the zumo token to the aad details. I'm wondering if there is a way to go from this login to the zumo sid.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you need directly, and I've documented this exact scenario in my book at http://aka.ms/zumobook in chapter 2 (Enterprise Authentication), with complete code samples.

Comment: I looked at chapter 2 and see how to get the zumo sid in the mobile app, but how do I get it if the user directly logs into my website using .auth/login/aad (I'm using Nancy, for example).

Comment: (I added a few more details, can you check?)

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe the only way to do this is to get the user details from the token, rather than the other way around. Extra query to .auth me though.

Comment: Where do you need the claims?  If on the client, cache the /.auth/me results.  If on the server, call GetAppServiceIDentityAsync<>() - it does not call /.auth/me.  Rather it uses an internal IIS mechanism to get the claims from the token store.

Comment: I decided just call GetAppServiceIdentityAsync as you suggested.

Comment: Any chance you can give me a hand with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916053/zumo-invokeapiasync-causes-signalr-to-stop-working